# Show all RowNumber records for duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table of string resources :

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id , 'john' AS name, 10 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 2 AS id , 'john' AS name, 10 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 3 AS id , 'john' AS name, 12 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 4 AS id , 'paul' AS name, 6 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 5 AS id , 'paul ' AS name, 6 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 6 AS id , 'paul different' AS name, 7 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 7 AS id , 'ringo' AS name, 2 AS age

)
```

So the name "john" has age of 10.

Later on  , someone else *(not me)* also added "john" with age 10.

So I want to clean all duplicates.

But that's not the problem. Before I delete I want to see all duplicates.

So I did this :

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT ID,
                  name,
                  age,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, age ORDER BY id) AS rn
           FROM   cte
           
       ) a  WHERE a.rn>1
ORDER BY
       name,
       age,
       a.rn
```

Result :

[image]

Which basically shows me duplicates. But I want to see also where `rn=1` only if there's more version for the current value.

**Question**

In other words : How can I enhance my query so :

- Show *all* versions for a record ( all row numbers , `rn`) only if there are versions for this record

Desired result :

```
ID  name    age rn
1   john    10  1
2   john    10  2
4   paul    6   1
5   paul    6   2
```

[**Sql online  - demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/268429)

NB I  know i can do it with rescanning the table for the same `name` and `age` . bUt I thought if there's more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists` operator to find the name which are `duplicated`. Try this.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id , 'john' AS name, 10 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 2 AS id , 'john' AS name, 10 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 3 AS id , 'john' AS name, 12 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 4 AS id , 'paul' AS name, 6 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 5 AS id , 'paul ' AS name, 6 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 6 AS id , 'paul different' AS name, 7 AS age
    UNION   
    SELECT 7 AS id , 'ringo' AS name, 2 AS age

)
, cte1
         AS (SELECT ID,
                    name,
                    age,
                    Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY name, age ORDER BY id) AS rn
             FROM   cte)
    SELECT *
    FROM   cte1 a
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   cte1 b
                   WHERE  a.name = b.name and a.age=b.age
                          AND b.rn > 1)
    ORDER  BY name, age, a.rn
```

or use `Inner Join`

```
    SELECT a.id,a.name,a.age
    FROM   cte1 a
           JOIN cte1 b
             ON a.name = b.name
                AND a.age = b.age
                AND b.rn > 1
    ORDER  BY a.name, a.age, a.rn
```

Or To do it in single table scan use `Dense_Rank` plus `window function`

```
    ;WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 AS id , 'john' AS name, 10 AS age
        UNION   
        SELECT 2 AS id , 'john' AS name, 10 AS age
        UNION   
        SELECT 3 AS id , 'john' AS name, 12 AS age
        UNION   
        SELECT 4 AS id , 'paul' AS name, 6 AS age
        UNION   
        SELECT 5 AS id , 'paul ' AS name, 6 AS age
        UNION   
        SELECT 6 AS id , 'paul different' AS name, 7 AS age
        UNION   
        SELECT 7 AS id , 'ringo' AS name, 2 AS age

    )
    , cte1
             AS (SELECT ID,
                        name,
                        age,
                        count(age) over (partition by name,age) cnt,
                        dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY age) AS rn
                 FROM   cte)
                 SELECT *
                 FROM   cte1
                 WHERE  rn = 1
                        AND cnt > 1
```

Comment: Thanks. you got my vote but I was hoping( like i said) to avoid rescan the table -- if possible :-)

Comment: The inner join solution works only for [2 versions records](http://i.imgur.com/0EnrT1x.png).  Try to add one more version to John and  - [the result is incorrect](http://i.imgur.com/ehozdxw.png). That's why i pinged you , because I thought about it on the way home, it just didn't make sense to me :-)